# Is it ok to have a Label tag in HTML alone that is by itself?

Tags: html, forms, syntax, tags, label

I want to know if this *code* is correct or not. Because a **label** tag in HTML should have an input tag as well. But the first line of code doesn't have any input with it.
For example:
I want to make this part of the *form*.
[image]

This is my code:

```
<label>Name:</label>
        <br>
     <div>   
        <label for="fname"></label>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="name" placeholder="First">
        <label for="lname"></label>
        <input type="text" id="lname" name="name" placeholder="Last">
     </div>
```

Comment: That's not what a `<label>` element is for, have you considered using a `<legend>` (if these elements are wrapped in a `<fieldset>` group, or perhaps a `<h2>` (or other heading element)? It seems to be valid HTML, but it's semantically incorrect.

Comment: Yup, I have tried to use <h2> but it came so big and moved further from the input. I still don't know what is <legend> as I'm new to web development.

Comment: A `label` does *not* have to have an input. You don't even need the `<br>`, because `div` is a block -- it will start a new line. "Proper" design would be to get rid of the first label and keep the labels inside the div, with text added, so users can click the labels.